# Getting the socket descriptor from the address?

Tags: c, udp, sendto

In `sendto`:

```
 ssize_t sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
              const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```

From this call I have the socket descriptor of the sending socket, is there a way to get the socket descriptor of the receiver from `const struct sockaddr *dest_addr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible. The socket descriptor you are asking to be retrieved is the socket descriptor of the receiver which for all that we know may be in some other process running in a totally different machine.

Also, I can't think of a reason as to what can be achieved by getting that socket descriptor.

Comment: The reason is to map the information of the sender and the receiver in a UDP communication.

Comment: To map the information between sender and receiver, you can use the three tuple of sending socket descriptor, receiver address and port. That should suffice.. right?

Comment: Anyways, you should abandon the idea of getting receiver's socket descriptor, it comes from another process and may hold a totally different meaning. For Ex: If you process sends UDP datagrams to 2 processes and both of them have receiving socket descriptor value as 10 (just an example), still your mapping won't work.. right?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is formally meaningless.

1. The socket descriptor of the receiver is in the receiving process. It is not available in the sending process, and even if it was it wouldn't be any use, as its value only has a meaning in the receiving process.
2. A UDP IP address:port may not map to a single socket anyway.